# Is it possible to prove that this is the optimal algorithm for searching in a grid?

Tags: algorithms

Imagine that some pirates have hidden some treasure at the point $(x, y)$ in a subset of  $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (in the range $1 \leq x \leq a$ and $1 \leq y \leq a$). Let us imagine that we have captured one such pirate, and they are willing (or perhaps willing if and only if they are threatened with the prospect of being forced to solve difficult maths problems) to evaluate the following function for a specific value $(u, v)$.

$$
\begin{equation}
f(u, v) =
\begin{cases}
2 \text{ if $(u, v) = (x, y)$} \\
1 \text{ if $u > x$ and $v > y$} \\
-1 \text{ if $u < x$ and $v < y$} \\
0 \text{ in all other cases} 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

My hypothesis is that the best worst-case running time is $O(\sqrt{n})$ ($n$ is the number of questions asked) by doing something similar to binary search on the array - we first partition the square by asking about the point $\left(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a}{2}\right)$ and then either (if the response is $1$ or $-1$ search in the top right or bottom left corner respectively - i.e. with $1$ call to $f$ we have divided the size of the search space by $4$), or in the other case we search the top left and bottom right corners (so we have to search 2 grids of size $\frac{a}{4}$), therefore, as a recurrence this is (in the worst case)

$$
\begin{equation}
T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + 1
\end{equation}
$$

Which has solution $T(n) = \sqrt{n} - 1$.

I considered trying to apply the binary tree proof to this question (i.e. that a binary tree with $n$ nodes has a minimum depth $\log_2(n)$), but I cannot think of a way to apply this to a 2d space.

Comment: I suggest to rewrite the function definition as $f(u,v)=\ldots$ instead of $f(a,b)=\ldots$. After all, $a<x$ of the third case looks like conflicting with the previously given bound $1\le x\le a$. -- Or do you mean to have bounds $1\le x\le n$ and $1\le y\le n$, perhaps? Or else, what even is then $n$ in $O(\sqrt n)$?

Comment: Thanks, updated!

Comment: You are still using $x,y$ to specify a point and then right after you are using them as dummy variables :P

Comment: Sorry, updated this again (I've been slowly mentally declining while trying to solve this problem)

Comment: Can't you cut it in half by asking about $(a, a/2)$?